# Выборка всех topic_id у которых есть определенный набор user_id

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте! Я плотно так застрял с одним вопросом и не могу найти ответ в поисковиках. Возможно просто потому что неправильно его формулирую. Если кто-то знает куда меня ткнуть, милости просим.

Тем не менее, имеется таблица вида:

```
| topic_id | user_id |
|--------------------|
|    1     |    3    |
|    1     |    1    |
|    2     |    3    |
|    2     |    2    |
|    3     |    3    |
|    3     |    2    |
|    4     |    3    |
|    4     |    4    |
|    4     |    1    |
|    13    |    3    |
|    13    |    1    |
|    13    |    1    |
|    24    |    3    |
```

Надо получить все `topic_id` у которых, к примеру, есть `user_id = 1` И `user_id = 3` (условий не обязательно будет два, возможен вариант где `user_id = {1, 2, 5, 8, 344}` и т.д.) т.е. исходя из таблицы мы должны получить `topic_id = {1, 4, 13}`.

Вопрос: Как написать такой SQL запрос?

Comment: У Вас немного странно выглядит таблица, имхо, - повторяются `topic_id`, но если так надо, то что мешает `SELECT topic_id FROM table WHERE user_id IN (....)` ?

Comment: О существовании `IN` знаю :) но все дело в том что `IN` работает как `OR` и если запустить запрос вида `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user_id IN (3,1)`, БД вернет `topic_id = {1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 24}`, что не удовлетворяет моим требованиям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT topic_id 
FROM tablename
WHERE user_id in (список) -- например (1,22,333)
GROUP BY topic_id 
HAVING COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ user_id) = N -- для показанного примера = 3
```

где N равно количеству ИДов в списке.

Если пара (topic_id, user_id) уникальна (имеется соотв. индекс) - комментарий удалить, иначе раскомментировать.

Comment: Спасибо! Это как раз то, что я искал. С `HAVING` как раз и не сообразил :( Только для того что бы все точь в точь получилось надо все таки `DISTINCT` раскомментировать: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = N`

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct topic_id from topic_table where user_id in (1,3...)`